# System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. (Parameter 'path') error unity 2021.1.18f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

I opened my project and this error appeared from unity editor, it doesn't show script that contains the error.

Before I opened this project I didn't have the error.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJQw4.png)

Full Error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. (Parameter 'path')at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)at ApiUpdater.MovedFromOptimizer.Program.Main(String[] args)--- End of inner exception stack trace ---at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Is this an error from Unity's editor or from your code when you run it?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama It's from Unity editor

Comment: And what was the code that threw the error. It seems fairly self explanatory

Comment: @BugFinder but this error doesn't show what the code threw the error.
this error occurs even after deleting all code containing commands from the System.IO namespace